# bitbucket.org claims "Unauthorized" during git push with Atlassian SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-for-windows

I'm using sourcetree to push my changes up to my repo. The issue I'm getting is that when I push to the repo I get this error

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v origin master:master
warning: encountered old-style '//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/workspace/projects/laravel-project' that should be '%(prefix)///wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/workspace/projects/laravel-project'
Pushing to bitbucket.org:cerberuspup/laravel-project.git
Unauthorized
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.



Completed with errors, see above.
```

and as far as I'm aware the repo does exist and I should have access rights

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your remote repos to see if those are the remotes you have access to with `git remote -v`. That will show you the remotes and if you are pushing to the one you think you have access to.

Comment: I did that and this is what I got `warning: encountered old-style '//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/workspace/projects/laravel-project' that should be '%(prefix)///wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/workspace/projects/laravel-project'
origin  git@bitbucket.org:cerberuspup/laravel-project.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:cerberuspup/laravel-project.git (push)
warning: encountered old-style '//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/workspace/projects/laravel-project' that should be '%(prefix)///wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/workspace/projects/laravel-project'
`

Comment: I have not used sourcetree for git before, but something that may help is deleting your .git file with ```rm -rf .git``` and then adding the remote repo again. I would not recommend this if this is a project where the git history is absolutely crucial though. @cerberusphp

Comment: @cerberusphp: The `warning: encountered old-style ...` message you're getting appears to be specific to Git-for-Windows. (It doesn't occur in the standard Git source anywhere.) It is unlikely to be related to your `git push` error.

Comment: Meanwhile, your url appears to be correct, so the problem is just that the ssh key you're using is not authorizing you to access this particular Git repository for this particular purpose. Note that Windows now comes with its own ssh implementation, while Git-for-Windows *also* comes with *its* own (and different) ssh implementation since very old Windows versions *don't* come with one. As the two ssh-es are slightly different, getting things correct for one doesn't always get things correct for the other.

Comment: You may need to poke around with your Git configuration to set `core.sshCommand` to force Git to use the ssh you want it to use (whichever that one is), and/or configure the Git version of ssh. To *test whether your ssh is configured correctly* use `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org`, choosing the ssh you prefer to run here.

Comment: By testing ssh without using Git at all, you remove one layer of possible issues. Once you have ssh working correctly (and the `ssh -Tv` test will tell you if it's working), you can then add Git back to the process and debug *just the Git part*.

Answer (score 0):

Type in `git remote -v` to make sure you in the right directory and right git repository.

Make sure you have repository privilege to push files (contributer / owner)

If you are, type in `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "yourmail@yourmail"`

You will be asked for passphrase, press enter few times.

After done, type in `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Copy all output,
Go to GitHub, Settings -> SSH and GPG -> ADD KEY, Paste your copied output.